# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined on javascript

Tags: javascript

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

This is message shown when I try to write:

```
/* Opacity Value */
const opacity = 0.4;

/* Set Opacity For First Image */
imgs[0].style.opacity = opacity;
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main-img">
      <img src="images/6.jpg" id="current" />
    </div>
    <div class="imgs">
      <img src="images/6.jpg" />
      <img src="images/5.jpg" />
      <img src="images/4.jpg" />
      <img src="images/6.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Full Javascript Code:

```
const current = document.querySelector("#current");
```

const imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".imgs img");

const opacity = 0.4;

imgs[0].style.opacity = opacity;

imgs.forEach(img => img.addEventListener("click", imgClick));

function imgClick(e) {
  imgs.forEach(img => (img.style.opacity = 1));

current.src = e.target.src;

current.classList.add("fade-in");

setTimeout(() => current.classList.remove("fade-in"), 500);

e.target.style.opacity = opacity;
}

Comment: Please, share your html and js code to be able to help you.

Comment: It basically says that imgs has no elements. So you can't access imgs[0]

Comment: So imgs[0] is undefined then. Show more code please.

Comment: this is my html

<div class="main-img">
          <img src="images/6.jpg" id="current" />
        </div>
        <div class="imgs">
          <img src="images/6.jpg" />
          <img src="images/5.jpg" />
          <img src="images/4.jpg" />
          <img src="images/6.jpg" />
        </div>

Comment: "imgs" << show us where it come from?

Comment: What is the value of `imgs`?

Comment: imgs it is a container div from all images and is write it in comment below

Comment: you need to provide the code where imgs is declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically in the below line, what you are doing is - you are calling an empty array's first index value and you are assigning the style property of it. You need to have value in the first index of the array to make that piece of code work.

```
imgs[0].style.opacity = opacity;
```

What you can do instead is

```
const opacity = 0.4;
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
if(imgs && imgs.length > 1) {
  imgs[0].style.opacity = opacity;
}
```

You have to keep the JS code in the end of your body section after all your html code to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.imgs img');
// imgs[0].style.opacity = 0.4; now you can set style to array element 
imgs.forEach((img, idx) => {
 setTimeout(() => {
   img.style.opacity = 0.4
  }, idx * 500)
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="main-img">
      <img src="images/6.jpg" id="current" />
    </div>
    <div class="imgs">
      <img src="images/6.jpg" />
      <img src="images/5.jpg" />
      <img src="images/4.jpg" />
      <img src="images/6.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```